# Microsoft edge multi element copy

Tags: html, web, extract, microsoft-edge

Does anyone know a fast way to copy multiple elements from an inspect page?
What I mean by that is I have a number of elements with same qualities i.e. same class and I want to copy all of them to my clipboard. Is there a way within inspect tool to do such a "trick" ? :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific simple way to do this, you can only using code to extract the elements you want.

For example if you want to get elements with the same class name, you can use the following code:

```
var outputText = "";
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');

for( var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++ ) {
  outputText += targets[i].outerHTML;
}
console.log(outputText);
```

Then you can copy the output in the console.